# Using a function that takes two parameters, return the sum of the square for each paramater

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im using sum_of_squares to return the sum of the square for each parameter. I am pretty lost with the returning the square for the paramaters.

```
def sum_of_squares(num1,num2):
return sum(int(c) ** 2 for c in str(num1,num2))
```

Comment: You can just `return num1**2 + num2**2`, no need to get all fancy.

Comment: @wim Easy enough haha! Thank you very much!

Comment: `str(num1,num2)` - you probably wanted to create a list, it's done with `[num1, num2]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str` only takes one argument, you can simply remove it to make the code work.

```
def sum_of_squares(num1, num2):
    return sum(int(c)**2 for c in (num1, num2))
```

as long as tuck `num1` and `num2` into an iterable structure.

For this very case, the more proper name is `sum_of_two_squares(num1, num2)`. Using `return num1**2+num2**2` is neater for this one.

But for more general function `sum_of_squares`, we can write it like:

```
def sum_of_squares(*args):
        return sum(int(c)**2 for c in args)
```

Comment: so what would be the difference of doing that, or doing this?def sum_of_squares(num1,num2):
    return num1**2 + num2**2]